# Name of database table Contact Form 7/ Flamingo forms are stored in?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wpengine, wordpress-flamingo-plugin

I’m using WPEngine to handle a dev and prod headless WordPress instance. I need to copy the dev environment over to prod, however I don’t want to overwrite any form submissions in prod that have been made. I have the option of not copying over specific database tables in WPEngine, but none of them look CF7 or Flamingo-related. Where are Flamingo and CF7 form submissions stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's helpful to someone in the future, the plugin author answered this question in the Wordpress forums:

```
They are stored as Custom Post objects so table names are wp_posts and wp_postmeta. You can export the data as XML through the Tools > Export admin menu.
```